# Integration of exponential function and square-wave

Tags: laplace-transform

How do I evaluate,
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{t} e^{c\tau}sqw(\frac{\tau}{T})d\tau
\end{equation}

where $$c < 0$$ and \$sqw(\cdot)\$ is a periodic function over \$t\in[0,T)\$,

\begin{equation}
sqw(t) = 
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \quad t < \frac{T}{2} \\
-1 & \quad t \geq \frac{T}{2}
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

I've tried using computer algebra systems but they yield nothing useful.

For context this is part of a convolution that gives me the output of a 2nd-order RLC circuit being driven by a square-wave. The reason I am trying to perform the convolution instead of some process involving Partial Fraction Decomposition (P.F.D) and the Inverse Laplace Transform is because this circuit is actually just the first of two stages. The whole system possesses a transfer function involving a third-degree polynomial so I would like to avoid the algebra involved in the necessary root extraction w/method of resolvents and subsequent P.F.D.

Comment: You may want the pure math stack exchange for this.

Comment: Okay thanks I was on the fence

Comment: Is \$\mathrm{sqw}(\cdot)\$ a periodic wave ? Please add the definition of \$\mathrm{sqw}\$ to the question. Use the [edit] button to do that.

Comment: perhaps decompose "sqw" into sum of many step functions, with various delay...

Comment: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782935/laplace-transform-of-a-square-wave-function)

Comment: If it helps, given the context, think of it as the integral of just \$\int_0^t\text{e}^{-c\tau}\text{d}\tau=(1-\text{e}^{-ct})/c\$ for the time the square wave is 1, then the same integral with a negative sign for the duration of -1, but with initial conditions from the end of the last segment, and so on. This being in time domain, of course, because your question doesn't make it clear which one you want: this, or frequency.